# Не получается установить библиотеку box2d

Tags: python, box2d

Сначала когда я пытался установить библиотеку через`pip install box2d`, вылезала ошибка связанная с тем, что у меня нет swig.exe. Я её устранил. Затем начала вылезать ошибка что у меня версия компилятора C++ старая или что-то подобное. Я скачал Visual Studio Build Tools. Ошибка устранилась и с помощью команды:`pip install --target=C:\Users\Я\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\venv\Lib\site-packages box2d --use-pep517` я наконец вроде бы без ошибок установил эту библиотеку, папка с библиотекой в папке site-packages появилась, но когда я запускаю программу: `import box2d`, вылезает ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'box2d'. Я не понимаю почему так, объясните как это исправить пожалуйста

Comment: Какую версию питона используете?

Comment: Какая операционая система?

Comment: Вы установили в PyCharm?

Comment: Использую python 3.9, Windows 10, да команды я в терминале Pycharm писал

Comment: Рекомендую в CMD установить, проверить роботоспособность модуля в консоли, а потом в настройках PyCharm выбрать нужный интерпретатор, а то "ВЫ" не почитав документацию как пользоваться PyCharm, делаете то что сами не понимаете. Сказав "ВЫ" я имел ввиду то что этот вопрос практически раз в неделю задают. Вы открывали Project structure? смотрели вообще как можно настроить проект?

Answer (score 0):

Выполните `pip install swig.exe`, затем `pip install ufal.pybox2d`